# How to calculate mode over two columns in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two columns in my csv: FirstName and LastName. I need to find the most common full name.
Eg:

```
FirstName      LastName  
A                 X  
A                 P  
A                 Y  
A                 Z                   
B                 X  
B                 Z  
C                 X  
C                 W  
C                 W
```

I have tried using the mode function:

```
df["FirstName"].mode()[0]  
df["LastName"].mode()[0]
```

But it wont work over two columns

The mode of each columns are :

FirstName : A - occurs 4 times
LastName : X - occurs 3 times

But the output should be "C W". As this is the full name that occur most times.

Answer (score 3):

You can do,

```
(df['FirstName'] + df['LastName']).mode()[0]

# Output : 'CW'
```

If you really need space in between first and last names you can concatenate ' ' like this,

```
(df['FirstName'] + ' ' + df['LastName']).mode()[0]
# Output : 'C W'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the columns and find mode,

```
df.apply(tuple, 1).mode()[0]

('C', 'W')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate those into a single string with:

```
full_names = df.FirstName + df.LastName
full_names.mode()[0]
```